# Setting the Graduated Filter Color Back to Default

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, adobe-camera-raw

Using Adobe Camera Raw 9.1.1 in CS6.

I was playing with the Graduated Filter and set its color field.

How do I set it back to no color? I am not able to find any way to have it back to its original value, it seems that now I am forced to use a color unless I am willing to delete all the development settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the color box so the dialogue box pops up that lets you choose a color. Set the color to white. The default color is white.